# How to initialize class static property once

Tags: class, typescript, static-methods

Here is my code where I am mocking the User object by initializing array or users and then defining the operations on it.

```
import IUser = require("../interfaces/IUser");

export class User implements IUser {

    private static users: User[] = [];

    constructor(public name: string) {

        this.name = name;        
        User.users.push(this);
    }

    private static init()
    {
       //creating some users           
       new User(/****/);
       new User(/****/);
       ... 
    }

    public static findOne(login: any, next:Function) {
        //finding user in users array
    }

    public static doSomethingelse(login: any, next:Function) {
        //doSomethingelse with users array
    }
}
```

Basically before doing `findOne(..)` `doSomethingelse()` I need `users` to be created and I do not want to do something like:

```
public static findOne(login: any, next:Function) {
            User.init();
            //finding user in users array
        }

        public static doSomethingelse(login: any, next:Function) {
            User.init();
            //doSomethingelse with users array
        }
```

Is there better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
export class User implements IUser {
    private static users = User.initUsers();

    constructor(public name: string) {

        this.name = name;        
        User.users.push(this);
    }

    private static initUsers()
    {
        User.users = [];
        new User(...);
        return User.users;
    }
}
```

Comment: why do I need line `return User.users;` ? Doesn't `User.users.push(this);` modifying `users` directly?

Comment: Is there something like `Java static block` in TypeScript? Was it in any issue - I looked for but didn't find.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize static variables in a "static" block.

```
import IUser = require("../interfaces/IUser");

export class User implements IUser {

    private static users: User[] = [];

    constructor(public name: string) {

        this.name = name;        
        User.users.push(this);
    }

    private static init()
    {
       //creating some users           
       new User(/****/);
       new User(/****/);
       ... 
    }

    public static findOne(login: any, next:Function) {
        //finding user in users array
    }

    public static doSomethingelse(login: any, next:Function) {
        //doSomethingelse with users array
    }
}
```

See [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Static_initialization_blocks)